I'm trying to replicate Rømer's experiment but can't seem to get even close to the correct value for the speed of light
I am trying to replicate Rømer's experiment where he determined the speed of light by observing and measuring the eclipse timings of Io by Jupiter. I'm using Stellarium for this experiment and no matter how I try I can't seem to land on the correct value.
Here is my setup.

Using Stellarium I noted the date and time of when Io just begins to emerge from behind Jupiter and took this as a baseline.
I then predict the next eclipse by adding 42.5 h to the previous time.
I use Stellarium to see when the next eclipse will happen and note the date and time.
I then calculate the distance travelled by using data from NASA'a Horizon website for the respective distances of Io from Earth, and subtract those 2 values, which gives the distance.
The predicted and actual eclipse timings are different by 104.5 s
Using these values I then divide the distance by the time.

Here are my values:

Baseline eclipse - 2023-11-01 07:00:46
Next predicted eclipse - 2023-11-01 01:28:20
Actual eclipse - 2023-11-01 01:26:35
Time difference = 104.5 sec

Distance of Io from Earth:

Baseline eclipse - 3.98457905366747 au = 596093026.42865 km (using 1 au=$1.496 \times 10^8$ km)
Actual eclipse - 3.98258042749088 au = 595794031.95264 km

So distance travelled = 298994.47602 km
Then to calculate speed:
$$
s = d / t \\
s = \frac{298994.47602 \text{ km}}{104.5 \text{ s}} \\
s = 2861.06 \text{ km/s}
$$
This is obviously incorrect and looks to be out by a factor of 100. I've double and triple checked all of my measurements and calculations, but I can't figure out where I've gone wrong.

Try picking the eclipses to be once when Earth and Jupiter are closest, and once when Earth and Jupiter are farthest.

I'll try that but shouldn't the calculation work no matter the distance?

I'm worried that your calculation is running into catastrophic cancellation. Using the periods at those two places maximises the chances that you get a correct value.

Ok so if I was to take measurements at those two locations then how do I go about predicting the times of the eclipses from the orbital period? Do I add 1.77 days to the first eclipse measurement and the to all subsequent measurements, or do I add I.77 days to the actual measured value?

Does the Stellarium simulation feature a finite speed of light?

There is a youtube video, on a channel named 'Tycho' where a nuclear physicist (formely an astrophysicist) is interested in replicating Rømer's finding, and under the motto 'anything done well can be simulated poorly' he used Stellarium to replicate Rømer's experiment. He reports that indeed Stellarium showed the 22 minutes phase shift for measurements half a year apart. At least that confirms that the Stellarium software reproduces the observational effects of the finite speed of light.

This is not replicating Romer's experiment, it is checking whether the Stellarium software with NASA's website describes astronomical observations correctly. To replicate Romer's experiment, you have to go out during night, make the actual observations and then analyze them.

@JánLalinský While you're correct, checking the simulation has the advantage of taking substantially less than six months to uncover this sort of analysis issue.

@rob This project is about checking the software and website data against the model and indeed it can reveal a consistency issue sooner than in half a year. Romer's experiment did not aim to uncover such an issue, it aimed to find the speed of light. It is not possible to do that by checking the simulation. So the title and the text are misleading and OP probably misinterprets what "replicating an experiment" means or uses language in a misleading way.

Rather than using Stellarium, you could try getting data directly from JPL Horizons, so that you know exactly what data you're getting. See https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons/ And if you can program, also see https://ssd-api.jpl.nasa.gov/doc/horizons.html It's a little more work than using Stellarium, but it gives you a lot more control.

@naturallyInconsistent Isn't it supposed to be when Earth is moving toward Jupiter, and when Earth is moving away from Jupiter? At the closest/farthest distances the relative velocity will be mostly tangential and the observed period will be the same in both cases.

@Aetol No. You are thinking of Doppler shift measurements. Rømer measured a straightforward travel time delay.

@rob Yes, that is essentially Doppler shift measurement, except with the frequency of Io's orbit rather than the frequency of light being shifted. Io's orbital period appears shorter when moving toward it and longer when moving away. Is that not what Rømer measured? What discrepancy could be observed by making measurements at opposition and conjunction instead?

In the current version of Stellarium, v24.2, there is a checkbox in the settings to turn "simulate light speed" on and off ("Sky and viewing options window" [F4] → "SSO" → "Simulate light speed", the same as in many older versions).  It sounds like you might have it turned off. I think that's the default, in order to save a computational step and run the program a little faster.
If this is correct, another interpretation is that you have discovered, by using a version of Rømer's method, that the speed of light in your Stellarium is wonky.  If the option is just disabled, however, I would have expected infinity rather than too slow by a factor of 100.
Another interpretation is that you have Stellarium correctly configured to simulate light speed, but the NASA database is also stimulating light speed, and your two data sources have some computational difference which means your two speed measurements are different at the 1% level.
Since you seem to be using consecutive eclipses, a third possibility is "catastrophic cancellation," as pointed out by another commenter.  Consider that
$$
10^6+1-10^6=1
$$
is true in arithmetic, but
$$
(10^6\pm10^3)+1-(10^6\pm10^3)=1\pm10^3
$$
means that any rounding or measurement uncertainty might obscure your effect.
The correct approach, as you have intuited in a comment, is to make the eclipse timing predictions yourself.  Here's an approach that I would take:

Measure the time interval for twenty or so consecutive Io orbits, so that you have a good handle for the average value and also for the repeatability of your method.

Repeat these measurements, keeping track of both dates and times, when Jupiter is at conjunction (distance 6 a.u.), at opposition (distance 4 a.u.), and then at the next conjunction.

You should find that Io's orbital period is the same for all three sets of observations, and that you can use the observations of transit times at the first conjunction to predict the transit times at the second conjunction.  (At conjunction and opposition, you won't get good eclipses.)  However, your transits at opposition should arrive about twenty minutes earlier than your conjunction-based predictions.


